# SQL query to return only 1 record per order based on if column does not have 0

Tags: mysql, sql

I've used this site for many months now and it has been very helpful. However i've finally come across a problem that i've been unable to find an answer for how to do.

My table has roughly 30 columns in it but im only interested in 7 of them. What im trying to accomplish is a query which will return the date/time of the first and last pick of each order but only for orders which have been completed.

my table looks something like this:

```
    ordnum | adddte          |pckdte            |pckqty |appqty | srcloc | ctnnum
-----------+-----------------+------------------+-------+-------+--------+------
    ORD123 | 4/20/16 6:31 AM | Null             | 1     | 0     |  375   |  CTN1
    ORD123 | 4/20/16 6:31 AM | 4/20/16 11:39 AM | 2     | 2     |  335   |  NULL
    ORD123 | 4/20/16 6:31 AM | 4/20/16 11:37 AM | 1     | 1     |  336   |  CTN1

    ORD456 | 4/20/16 7:11 AM | 4/20/16 11:59 AM | 3     | 3     |  376   |  CTN2
    ORD456 | 4/20/16 7:11 AM | 4/20/16 11:47 AM | 1     | 1     |  345   |  CTN2
    ORD456 | 4/20/16 7:11 AM | 4/20/16 11:07 AM | 4     | 4     |  355   |  CTN2
```

Please note the only way to tell if an order is complete is each of its appqty has a value greater than 0. Its pckdte can be null and the order still be competed.

Below is the code im currently using which does give me the start and stop times of each order but also includes order which have not been completed yet.

```
SELECT 
      ordnum
      ,max(pckdte) AS "Last Pick"
      ,min(pckdte) AS "First Pick"
  FROM MyTable
  Where (adddte >= '2016-04-02 00:00:00' AND  pckdte <= '2016-04-20 23:59:59')

 and ctnnum like 'c%'
 and (srcloc like '2%' or srcloc like '3%' or srcloc like '4%' or srcloc like '5%' or srcloc like '1%')
group by ordnum
order by ordnum
```

The code gives me these results:

```
    ordnum  | Last Pick        |   First Pick
------------+------------------+----------------
    ORD123  | 4/20/16 11:39 AM | 4/20/16 11:37 AM
    ORD456  | 4/20/16 11:59 AM | 4/20/16 11:07 AM
```

However I do not want to include ORD123 as there is still an uncompleted pick (appqty = 0). Columns adddte, srcloc, and ctnnum are needed to separate my department's orders from everyone else's as they are all stored on the same table and the parameters outlined in my where statement is the only way to filter out my department's work.

Any help on this problem would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if i need to provide additional information.

Comment: add after group by a `HAVING SUM(appqty = 0)=0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add one line to check make sure the appqty = 0 for an ordnum doesn't exist

```
SELECT 
      ordnum
      ,max(pckdte) AS "Last Pick"
      ,min(pckdte) AS "First Pick"
  FROM MyTable
  Where (adddte >= '2016-04-02 00:00:00' AND  pckdte <= '2016-04-20 23:59:59')
 and ctnnum like 'c%'
 and (srcloc like '2%' or srcloc like '3%' or srcloc like '4%' or srcloc like '5%' or srcloc like '1%')
 -- line below added
 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MyTable T2 WHERE appqty = 0 AND T2.ordnum = MyTable.ordnum)      
group by ordnum
order by ordnum
```

Answer (score 2):

Subquery should work:

```
AND ordnum not in (SELECT ordnum FROM MyTable WHERE appqty = 0)
```

This will filter out all `ordnum` that have at least one row with an `appqty` of `0`.

Full query:

```
SELECT 
      ordnum
      ,max(pckdte) AS "Last Pick"
      ,min(pckdte) AS "First Pick"
  FROM MyTable
  Where (adddte >= '2016-04-02 00:00:00' AND  pckdte <= '2016-04-20 23:59:59')

 and ctnnum like 'c%'
 and (srcloc like '2%' or srcloc like '3%' or srcloc like '4%' or srcloc like '5%' or srcloc like '1%')
 AND ordnum not in (SELECT ordnum FROM MyTable WHERE appqty = 0)
group by ordnum
order by ordnum
```

Comment: If you provided a little bit of explanation as to how exactly your proposed solution works and where you insert it into the above query, then it would be a perfect answer.

Comment: Good comment and you're right.  I was editting in the full answer and got sidetracked.

Answer (score 0):

I Think You Should create a View with  adding column  Min(appqty) as MAPPQTY
then Filter  with MAPQTY>0

will Solved your Problem

Comment: Sadly I dont have permissions to create things or edit existing tables/views. If I did then several of my other problems would be easily solved :/